# adding FULLTEXT index : didn't make much difference , is it going to index older data?

Tags: mysql, indexing, myisam, full-text-indexing

i have a query which is using a `like` condition and it's killing my server 
(this query is what i get frequently in the slow-query-log ) 
 btw  my table has about 120k rows  - pleas ignor the syntax errors

```
select * from `images` where `category` like `%,3,%` and ( `tags` like '%,tag1,%' or `tags` like '%,tag2,%' or `tags` like '%,tag3,%' or `tags` like '%,tag4,%')
```

i don't want to change the query and database design fro now , so i've decided to switch to myisam and use fulltext index for `tags` column .

afterward server load hasn't change that much , mysql still using up to 90% of cpu (1 out of 8 of curse) from time to time .

so i was wondring , this fulltext indexing ... is it going to index the older data ( before adding this index ) ? cuz it happend very fast and my table is kinda big .

or it's only going to work on the newly stored data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existing data was indexed, but as advised by Pyrce, a query with `LIKE %[token]%` is unable to leverage a fulltext index.

Rewrite your condition like this, this strictly equivalent to your inital query (ignoring [stopwords and the likes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)):

```
WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However you should rather focus on normalizing your structure. Storing non-scalar values (such as coma-separated values) in a field violates the very [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Create a new `image_tag` table and establish a 1-N relationship with `images`. A regular index will allow instant querying.

```
CREATE TABLE image_tags (
    image_id INT,
    tag VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (image_id, tag),
    FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES images(id), -- replace with "images" table's actual primary key
    KEY(tag, image_id) -- this index may be superfluous, check EXPLAIN
);

SELECT images.*
FROM images
JOIN image_tags ON image_id = images.id
WHERE tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4');
```

Repeat with `images.category`.

Answer (score 2):

Full-text indexing usually only helps with prefix matching on tokens. In other words, all non-alphanumeric plus underscore separated words (anything other than A-Z, 0-9, or _ separates a word -- see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)) within each row for the `tags` column will be indexed for prefix matches. You then have to use `MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('tag1')` to match the full text index search. You can repeat these matches for each tag to get your full query. Doing an [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) query will tell you if the query builder is using your index once you get the match queries fully configured.

Unfortunately MySQL is rather limited in how you can alter the full text indexing/searching -- so you're mostly stuck with it's default search methods (there's a couple search modes for fulltext -- see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)).

Comment: sorry , i've updated the query .. tags are seperated with `,` ... so your saying in order to fulltext works i have to go with  => where tags like '%,tag1,'  ?

Comment: Well apparently after looking into the problem MySQL is much less capable than Postgres in this realm... See http://makandracards.com/makandra/13693-customize-tokenization-of-the-mysql-fulltext-parser. You'll need to change the rows to not use `,` separators or to write a C plugin to MySQL (not suggested). I'll update my answer.